# SwiftUI: UIkit UIbezier to SwiftUI Path

Tags: swiftui, uibezierpath, cgpoint

I am trying to convert UIBezierPath to SwiftUI Path

I managed to do manually, by editing the  bellow code:

From:

**UIBezierPath**
controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 1226.38, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1199.37, y: 0))

To:

**SwiftUI**
control1: CGPoint(x: 1226.38, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 1199.37, y: 0))

Example of a a full path code:

```
       let stroke253 = UIBezierPath()
            stroke253.move(to: CGPoint(x: 1253.45, y: 0))
            stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 1172.3, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 1226.38, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1199.37, y: 0))
            stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 990.46, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 1111.66, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1051.12, y: 0))
            stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 808.64, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 929.82, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 869.27, y: 0))
            stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 626.74, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 747.98, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 687.4, y: 0))
            stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 444.84, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 566.08, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 505.5, y: 0))
            stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 263, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 384.18, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 323.63, y: 0))
            stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 81.18, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 202.37, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 141.82, y: 0))
            stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint.zero, controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 54.11, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 27.07, y: 0))
            context.saveGState()
            context.translateBy(x: 128.21, y: 144.05)
            stroke253.lineWidth = 2
            UIColor(hue: 1, saturation: 0.636, brightness: 0.549, alpha: 1).setStroke()
            stroke253.stroke()
            context.restoreGState()

            context.restoreGState()
        }
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct PatternScene: View {
   let stroke253 = Path { stroke253 in
       stroke253.move(to: CGPoint(x: 1253.45, y: 0))
    stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 1172.3, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 1226.38, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 1199.37, y: 0))
    stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 990.46, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 1111.66, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 1051.12, y: 0))
    stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 808.64, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 929.82, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 869.27, y: 0))
    stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 626.74, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 747.98, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 687.4, y: 0))
    stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 444.84, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 566.08, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 505.5, y: 0))
    stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 263, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 384.18, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 323.63, y: 0))
    stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 81.18, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 202.37, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 141.82, y: 0))
    stroke253.addCurve(to: CGPoint.zero, control1: CGPoint(x: 54.11, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 27.07, y: 0))
    }


    var body: some View {
        self.stroke253
            .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 10)

    }
}

struct PatternScene_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PatternScene()
    }
}
```

Question: how can I do that without manually editing?

Appreciate any help!

cheers

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand your question clearly, or miss some infos. But if you need just convert a `UIBezierPath` to `Path`:

`Path(UIBezierPath().cgPath)` or `Path(stroke253.cgPath)` as your variable.